# MySQL invalid repetition count(s)' from regexp

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having an issue with a query I'm running on MySQL that contains some regex, here it is: `SELECT * FROM dump WHERE Hours REGEXP '^\d{337}1{8}'`

When I test my regex separately it's working fine, here's some sample data that it matches with:

`000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000`

Any idea where it fails?

Comment: How is it failing?

Comment: The maximum number of repetitions is 255 ([See here](http://rextester.com/NQVWB52748)).  One workaround is to break up the pattern into two parts.  See the duplicate link for more information.

Comment: Also `\d` is not supported; see the other duplicate link.

Comment: Thanks Tim & Ic that worked